# Flutter Image height adjusted according to column

Tags: flutter, image, layout

I want to achieve following layout:

[image]

I have `Row`, in which there are:

- `Image` (fixed width)
- `Column` (consists of few `Text` elements.)

I would like to achieve that `Image` height would be adjusted according to `Column` height.
I tried to wrap `Image` in `Expanded`, bot it did not lead to the result. I cannot use `SizedBox` either because the `Text` elements in `Column` can have different height (they may have one or two lines each), therefore height cannot be calculated. Can somebody advise?

Comment: seems like a job for [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap you `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight`. (It will take as much space available for Row considering child widget)

```
IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://file-examples.com/storage/fe1134defc6538ed39b8efa/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg",
                  width: 120, // can change as per need
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),

              // flexible column
              const Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "lorem ipusm  lorem ipusm lorem ipusm lorem ipusm lorem ipusm lorem ipusm lorem ipusm lorem ipusm",
                    ),
                    Text("hello")
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: check image output for above code]

Comment: And how to stretch the image on the left side? Container is working according to your guide, however not an Image.

Comment: can you please share image link as i tried with sample image it's working properly

Comment: OK, can you please edit your answer and provide working code with any rectangular Image?

Comment: edited please check